# TAR command not executing properly

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script, that executes several functions, each one of those generating a set of system information. After those functions are executed, I call a different function, which will make a tar archive, containing the files/folders generated from the previous functions.

Example gather information function

```
system_inf (){
cat /etc/ntp.conf >> ~/info_prepped/system/NTP_server_configuraiton.txt
ip a >> ~/info_prepped/system/ip.txt
}
```

prepare folders

```
info_prep () {
find ~/info_prepped -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; >> ~/info_prepped/authenticity.txt
tar -zcvf /tmp/"$(uname -n)".tar ~/info_prepped
}
```

then, when unfortunately when I run them like this, all files and folders are generated properly, but nothing gets archived in the tar:

```
system_inf
info_prep
```

I have to run the script a second time and comment out the system_inf function, for the info_prep to work.

I've tried with sleep, and some other ideas from the internet, but with little success.

Thanks in advance and wish you a great week ahead.

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't use the tilde (`~`) in my scripts ever. Please use $HOME or specify the full path.

Comment: Do you know about `set -x`? Do all the directories exist already?

Comment: tar would give you error message when something wouldn't work (like gzip not found or missing permissions)

Comment: It is unlikely that you do not get at least an error message if this does not work. So please report that error messages.

Comment: Run `tar` through `strace`: `strace -o tar.strace tar ...` and add the content of `tar.strace` to your question (as a link if it is too much).

Comment: i can't reproduce that issue, i doubt that this question can be answered

Comment: What's your `$BASH_VERSION` and your OS name + version (e.g. Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04, etc)? Not all implementations of Bash are equivalent.